# Finding the limits when integrating a complex number

Tags: complex-integration

Evaluate $\int_c f(z) dz$ from $z(0,0)$ to $z=2+4i$ where $f(z)=x^2 -iy^2$
I know how to work this out and I know the answer is $24+\frac{8}{5}i$

However I do not understand why the limits for x are $0 \to 2$ and for y are $0 \to 4$

Comment: $z=x+iy=(x,y)$. Now $z_0=(0,0)=0+0i$ and $z_1=2+4i=(2,4)$...

Comment: I do not believe $f$ to be analytic.  Then the integral between the two points is path-dependent.  I take it somewhere in the problem there is a specification that the integral is to be taken over a straight line between the endpoints.